# How to dynamically assign property from method in Ruby

Tags: ruby, methods, properties, attributes, variable-assignment

I have a method

```
def populate destination, source

end
```

where **destination** is always one of the following values: "ax", "bx", "cx", "dx". In the class that contains that method I have @ax, @bx, @cx, @dx. How can I assign the correct property(attribute) from the method body if **destination** changes dynamically and I know it runtime in the body of the method.

I was trying with the **send** method like this:

```
self.send(destination, source)
```

but it gives me an error.

I have defined the properties like this:

```
attr_accessor :ax, :bx, :cx, :dx
```

**EDIT:**

The method itself:

```
def populate destination, source
      receiver = destination
      if source == :ax then self.send(:populate, receiver , @ax_real) end
      if source == :bx then self.send(:populate, receiver , @bx_real) end
      if source == :cx then self.send(:populate, receiver , @cx_real) end
      if source == :dx then self.send(:populate, receiver , @dx_real) end
      if source.class != Symbol then self.send(:populate, receiver , source) end
end
```

this gets me into endless recursion.

Comment: what you are trying to do here `if source == :ax then self.send(:populate, receiver , @ax_real) end` ?

Comment: Are you trying to do `@ax= :ax`,`@bx= :bx` etc,, ?

Comment: if source is :ax then I want to set the property value that comes from destination(ax, bx, cx, dx) and assign it with the value of another property @ax_real.
E.g. if receiver was :cx I would like to to this '@cx_real' = '@ax_real'.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Yes, exactly that. But it depends. It might be '@bx', '@cx' etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below to remove the error:

```
 self.send(:populate,destination, source)
```

Look also [`Object#send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Object.html#method-i-send)

> ***Invokes the method identified by symbol, passing it any arguments specified***. You can use `__send__` if the name send clashes with an existing method in obj. When the method is identified by a string, the string is converted to a symbol.

**update**

```
def populate destination, source
  if source == :ax then send(:ax= ,@ax_real) end
  if source == :bx then send(:bx= , @bx_real) end
  if source == :cx then send(:cx= , @cx_real) end
  if source == :dx then send(:dx= , @dx_real) end
end
```

*Doing re-factoring*:

```
def populate destination, source
  send("#{source}=",instance_eval("@#{source}_real"))
end
```

Comment: But why do I have to pass the name of the method 'populate' in self.send? When I skip it it gives me ArgumentError.

Comment: @user2128702 Look at the method documentation, I linked.

Comment: When I use it like this in my code I get into stack oveflow. Maybe there is a recursion that keeps on calling the method itself. That is why I am wondering that I am doing self.send(:populate, destination, source) inside of the populate method itself.

Comment: I am not sure if it works for me because there is an endless recursion of method calls. I will update my question

Comment: @user2128702 see the update.. and tell me anything more?

Comment: Dou you think it would work if I used it like this:
send("@#{receiver}=" ,@ax_real) end , so I can do it dynamically?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45028/discussion-between-arup-rakshit-and-user2128702)

Comment: @muistooshort I just noticed it.. I have changed it.